# How to set multiple images from gallery to imageViews in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I can select multiple images from gallery, but when I try to set them, these images aren't sorted correctly in my Imageviews. I want the first selected image the be placed in first ImageView, so on. How can I sort these images ?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {


                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);


                        // Get the cursor
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                        cursor.close();
                    }

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),mArrayUri.get(0));
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if(mArrayUri.get(1) != null) {

                        bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(1));
                        imageview2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
                        imageview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if(mArrayUri.get(2) !=null ){
                        bitmap3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(2));
                        imageview3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
                        imageview3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
```